# R Run knitr from a batch-file (windows)

Tags: r, batch-file, knitr

I run some automatic reports each day with batch-files on my windows-computer. But how do I do this with a .rmd file and generate the html-output?

So, this works for me using a batchfile with a normal .R file:

```
"C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --default-packages=methods 
"C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Scripts\models.R"
```

But, this won't:

```
"C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --default-packages=methods,knitr 
"C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Scripts\test_knitr.Rmd"
```

I've tried some variations inspired by command-line like:

```
"C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" --default-packages=methods,knitr 
knit("C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Scripts\test_knitr.Rmd")
```

But no succes so far! Im a total knitr/.rmd newbee, so I'm not even sure it can be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use something along the lines

```
Rscript -e "require ('knitr'); knit ('test.Rmd')"
```

Comment: But this is for use with the command-line right? The syntax for batch files are different? At least I've tried a lot of variations of what you've written and can't get it to work.

Comment: If you find a difference between batch and command line, it mostly caused by different paths involved. Try to do a `cd <full path of test.rmd>` first in the batch file.

Comment: It's also possible you might have to define the path to Rscript. This worked for me: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" -e "library(knitr); knit('myFile.Rmd')"`

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\Rscript.exe" -e "library('knitr'); knit('C:/Users/test_doc.Rmd')"
pause
```

Like "cbeleites supports Monica" said using the full path.

Don't forget that in R we must use "/" and not "\" like in Windows.

So in the R call we use "\" because we are talking to Windows
and in the knit we use "/" because we are talking to R.

I hope it help.